# how to dynamically change an element content after with Jquery click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on below jQuery code and target is to change content of any  tag is clicked by the user.

I am fine with getting the id of clicked element but not able change its content.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("td").click(function(){
            var elementID = $(this).attr('id');
            alert(elementID); //I am OK by accessing the elementID
            $("#elementID").text("X"); // How pass this elementId again in order to change content ?
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `$(this)`, just like you did in the first row of the function...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have the element by accessing `$(this)`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td").click(function(){
        $(this).text("X");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, need to have more understanding about basics :))

Answer (score -1):

correct your line with this: `$("#"+elementID).text("X");`

Comment: Correct it to what?

Answer (score -2):

```
$("td").click(function(){
   var elementID = $(this).attr('SomeOtherElementID');
   $("#" + elementID).text("X");
});
```

Comment: I think it is a better way to do it directly with `$(this).text('X')`

Comment: I think that by doing this he doesn't want to change $(this) element. Probably, he would like just to get SomeOtherElementID and change it's content.

Comment: in your case `SomeOtherElementID ` isnt some-other-element -> You try to access an attribute on the clicked element. So in your example the `<td>` tag need a `<td  SomeOtherElementID="otherElementId">` and I don't think that this would help @crowley